# How to create a secure token for an app?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, token

Im working on a simple app, that allow the user to login. Im using an ajax function pass the values to a PHP file(on a different domain). If the user and the password are correct the page display echo"success" and im using that word to validate and create a random key to allow the user access to a private page.

I was reading that you can also add a header token, it is possible to add that to my current code..
Iam new in developing "app", hope some one can point in the right direction on what is the best way to do this.

```
var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#pass").val();


    var dataString = "username="+username+"&pass="+password+"&insert="; 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url",
        data: dataString,
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {$('#loginButton').val('Connecting...');},
        success: function(data)
        { 
            if(data == " success")
            {
                alert("Success");
                returnHash(); 
            }

            if(data == " Login failed")
            {
                alert("There's a problem with username/password!");
                $('#loginButton').val('Submit');  
            }
        }
    });

function returnHash()
{
    letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890".split("");
    window.token=""; 
    for(i=0;i<64;i++){
         window.token += letters[Math.floor(Math.random()*letters.length)];
    }
    success();
}
```

Comment: You were reading where?

Answer (score 1):

To create a **real** unique hash, use the current time with an random generated number like in the code below:

```
var dateForHash = (new Date()).valueOf().toString();
var createRandomNum = Math.random().toString();
crypto.createHash('sha1').update(dateForHash + createRandomNum).digest('hex');
```

You can also use `crypto.randomBytes()`- this hash is practical unique but not theoretical.

```
var hash = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');
```

I would recommend the second way for this type of use.